# RedBean Data Not Synchronized

Tags: php, orm, redbean

So, I've been trying to use RedBean PHP in my latest projects, and now I'm faced with this weird problem.

I have a simple data structure, Provinces and Countries, and I have this code to save the Province data to my database :

```
$app->post('/admin/provinces/add', function () use ($app)
{
    $province = R::dispense('province');
    $province->name = $app->request()->post('name');

    $country = R::load('country', $app->request()->post('country_id'));
    $country->ownProvince[] = $province;

    $errors = array();

    if (!V::alpha()->notEmpty()->validate($province->name)) $errors[] = 'Province name is required!';

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $id = R::store($province);
        R::store($country);
        $app->redirect(BASE_PATH.'admin/provinces/view/'.$id, 301);
    } else {
        $app->flash('errors', $errors);
        $app->redirect(BASE_PATH.'admin/provinces/add', 301);
    }
});
```

This code works well, the relationship between the Province and the Country data are saved successfully. I can access the Country data from the Province bean vice versa just fine.

However, when I imported the existing province data to my database from other database, I cannot access the Country data from the Province data with this code :

**Controller**

```
$app->get('/admin/provinces', function () use ($app)
{
    $provinces = R::findAll('province', 'ORDER BY name');
    R::preload($provinces, array('country'));

    $app->render('admin/provinces/index.html.twig', array(
        'provinces' => $provinces
    ));
});
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">{{ b.a("admin/provinces?order=id", "ID") }}</th>
            <th style="width: 45%">{{ b.a("admin/provinces?order=provincename", "Name") }}</th>
            <th style="width: 45%">{{ b.a("admin/provinces?order=provincename", "Country") }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for province in provinces %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ province.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.a("admin/provinces/view/"~province.id, province.name) }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.a("admin/countries/view/"~province.country.id, province.country.name) }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The strange thing is, this code works :

**Controller**

```
$app->get('/admin/provinces/view/:id', function ($id) use ($app)
{
    $province = R::load('province', $id);
    $country = $province->country;

    $app->render('admin/provinces/view.html.twig', array(
        'province' => $province,
        'country' => $country
    ));
});
```

**View**

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name</dt><dd>{{ province.name }}</dd>
    <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{ b.a("admin/countries/view/"~country.id, country.name) }}</dd>
</dl>
```

So, where did I gone wrong? Why can I display the Country data from a single Province, but I cannot with get the related Country from multiple Provinces?

Also, if I input the Province data manually, all of those codes works fine. However, it doesn't work if I import the data from another database

I'm using the latest RedBean (downloaded the rb.php yesterday) by the way.

Comment: It's probably a problem with your templating engine. RedBean fetches bean data on-demand, and maybe the engine you use somehow overrides this behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround, but I don't think it's the most efficient way of doing things...

```
$app->get('/admin/provinces', function () use ($app)
{
    $provinces = R::findAll('province', 'ORDER BY name');
    R::preload($provinces, array('country'));

    // Reiterate through all of the beans to load the related bean
    foreach ($provinces as $province) {
        $province->country;
    }

    $app->render('admin/provinces/index.html.twig', array(
        'provinces' => $provinces
    ));
});
```